# Limitation of spaces in regex string

Tags: regex

Total regex newbie here and I have been all over the place to try and find an answer. I need to add exactly 1 space followed by a string of letter characters (min 3 max 30) I have the following but it will accept more than 1 space which is the problem:

```
^[:blank:][A-z]{3,30}$
```

Any help with this would be great

Comment: Have you tried `[[:blank:]]`?  [Sticking your regex into regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aY6lD2/1) shows that the posix classes have to be contained within character classes

Answer (score 2):

`[A-z]` will also capture `` [, \, ], ^, _, ` ``.

Use this regex to allow **exactly 1** space in the beginning and then 3 to 30 English letters:

```
^[[:blank:]][a-zA-Z]{3,30}$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/aY6lD2/3).

[image]

Comment: why you change  `[[:blank:]]` as optional?

Comment: @AvinashRaj: OP is not clear about what "adding" means. Do you know? I read it as allow 1 space, but in the original regex attempt, there is a space, and it is not working...

Comment: `I need to add exactly 1 space followed by a string of letter characters (min 3 max 30)`

Comment: Ok, I added one more option in case that is what OP needs.

Comment: sorry for not being clear. I need the validation to be 1 space followed by a minimum of 3 and a maximum of 30 letters (space can only preceed the letters and cannot appear anywhere else)

Comment: @RichardW1: I edited the answer. I've only kept the regex that requires 1 space (or tab! - but I guess it is what you want). If you only need space, I'd use a literal space: `^ [a-zA-Z]{3,30}$`

Answer (score 0):

To be unicode compatible:

```
^\p{Zs}\p{L}{3,30}$
```

Where `\p{Zs}` stands for a space character
and `\p{L}` stands for a letter.

Comment: Cheers stribizhev. Worked perfectly. I couldn't work out what flavour of regex we use (bear in mind I'm a total noon) but you hit the nail right on the head. Hats off to you sir!